# Unanalyzed fields on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, field, kibana

i need help to correct kibana field. when I try to visualizing the fields, shown me the following warning:

> Careful! The field contains Analyzed selected strings. Analyzed
>   strings are highly unique and can use a lot of memory to visualize.
>   Values: such as bar will be foo-foo and bar broken into. See Core
>   Mapping Types for more information on setting esta field Analyzed as
>   not

Comment: What problem do you have exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch default dynamic mapping is to analyze any string field (break the field into tokens, for instance: aaa_bbb_ccc will be break down into aaa,bbb and ccc).

If you do not want such behavior you must change the mapping settings 
**before any document was pushed into the index**.

You have two options to do that:

1. Change the mapping for a particular index using mapping API, in a [static](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) way or [dynamic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html) way (dynamic means that the mapping will be applies also to fields that still does not exist in the index)
2. You can change the behavior of any index according to a pattern, [using the template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

This example shows a template that changes the mapping for any index that starts with "app", applying "not analyze" to any field in any type and make sure "timestamp" is a date (good for cases in with the timestamp is represented as a number of seconds from 1970):

```json
{
  "template": "myindciesprefix*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp_field": {
            "match": "timestamp",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really you dont have any problem is only a message of info, but if you dont want analyzed fields when you build your index in elasticsearch you must indicate that one field is a not analyzed field.